How to determine the correlation between a discrete variable and a continuous variable?
I have 9 conditions (discrete variables) with each having only two states: occurrence (corresponding to 1) and non-occurrence (corresponding to 0), resulting in a total of approximately 511 combinations (excluding the cases where nothing occurs). Each combination corresponds to a result value (continuous variable) ranging from 0 to 100.
I want to know the contribution of each condition to the result value, i.e., which condition makes it easier for the result value to become larger, and which conditions have little impact on the result value.
Furthermore, if I have more conditions (up to a maximum of 34 conditions), how can I expand upon this approach?

Could you explain why the standard approaches, such as regression coefficients or Pearson correlation coefficients, might not be adequate for your purpose?

@whuber Because as far as I know, the Pearson correlation coefficient is more commonly used for the correlation calculation between two consecutive variables. I am uncertain about its credibility when applied to the correlation between a discrete variable and a continuous variable. Especially in my case, the discrete variable has only two possible values: 0 and 1.

That myth is a FAQ: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pearson+correlation+binary.
